# Appium Error : A new session could not be created. (Original error: Did not get session redirect from Chromedriver)

Tags: java, selenium, appium

I am trying to run my first test through Appium and getting the below error.

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: A new session could not be created. (Original error: Did not get session redirect from Chromedriver) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Command duration or timeout: 4.64 seconds
Build info: version: '2.41.0', revision: '3192d8a', time: '2014-03-27 17:17:32'
os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_51'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
```

**Appium Logs:**

```
ERROR: debug: Appium request initiated at /wd/hub/session
info: Looks like we want chrome on android
info: Creating new appium session 99ff77a0-86fa-4851-93ad-5375c95656e7
ERROR: debug: executing: "D:\****\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140321\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" devices
info: Preparing device for session
info: Not checking whether app is present since we are assuming it's already on the device
info: Checking whether adb is present
info: [ADB] Using adb from D:\****\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140321\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
info: Trying to find a connected android device
info: [ADB] Getting connected devices...
info: [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
ERROR: debug: executing: "D:\****\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140321\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s emulator-5554 wait-for-device
info: Setting device id to emulator-5554
info: [ADB] Waiting for device to be ready and to respond to shell commands (timeout = 5)
ERROR: debug: executing: "D:\****\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140321\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s emulator-5554 shell "echo 'ready'"
info: Starting logcat capture
ERROR: debug: Pushing unlock helper app to device...
ERROR: debug: executing: "D:\****\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140321\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s emulator-5554 install "C:\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\unlock_apk\unlock_apk-debug.apk"
ERROR: debug: executing: "D:\****\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140321\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s emulator-5554 shell "dumpsys window"
info: Writing dumpsys output to C:\Appium\node_modules\appium\.dumpsys.log
ERROR: debug: Screen already unlocked, continuing.
info: Creating Chrome session
info: Ensuring Chromedriver exists
info: Killing any old chromedrivers, running: FOR /F "usebackq tokens=5" %a in (`netstat -nao ^| findstr /R /C:"9515 "`) do (FOR /F "usebackq" %b in (`TASKLIST /FI "PID eq %a" ^| findstr /I chromedriver.exe`) do (IF NOT %b=="" TASKKILL /F /PID %b))
info: No old chromedrivers seemed to exist
info: Spawning chromedriver with: C:\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\chromedriver\windows\chromedriver.exe
info: [CHROMEDRIVER] Starting ChromeDriver (v2.9.248315) on port 9515
info: Making http request with opts: {"url":"http://****:9515/wd/hub/session","method":"POST","json":{"sessionId":null,"desiredCapabilities":{"chromeOptions":{"androidPackage":"com.android.browser","androidActivity":"com.android.browser.BrowserActivity","androidDeviceSerial":"emulator-5554"}}}}
ERROR: debug: executing: "D:\****\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140321\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s emulator-5554 devices
info: [CHROMEDRIVER STDERR] [0.003][SEVERE]: Could not bind socket to 0.0.0.0:9515
info: [CHROMEDRIVER] Port not available. Exiting...
info: Chromedriver exited with code 1
info: [ADB] Getting connected devices...
ERROR: error: Chromedriver create session did not work. Status was 200 and body was {"sessionId":"ba9a494082776d6b4836da850072cbcb","status":13,"value":{"message":"unknown error: Device emulator-5554 is already in use\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248315,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86)"}}
info: Cleaning up appium session
ERROR: error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Did not get session redirect from Chromedriver
info: Error: Did not get session redirect from Chromedriver
    at null. (C:\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\devices\android\chromedriver.js:195:12)
    at Request._callback (C:\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\devices\common.js:104:5)
    at Request.self.callback (C:\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\request\request.js:121:22)
    at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at Request. (C:\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\request\request.js:985:14)
    at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at IncomingMessage. (C:\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\request\request.js:936:12)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:920:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
info: Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: Did not get session redirect from Chromedriver)","origValue":"Did not get session redirect from Chromedriver"},"sessionId":null}
```

**I want to use only Android default Browser and not Chrome. I dont know why Appium is trying to launch Chromedriver and Chrome Browser. Below is the code i used.**

```
import java.net.URL;                

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;                
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;                
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;                
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;                
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;                
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;                
import org.testng.annotations.Test;                

public class Appium {                

    public WebDriver driver;            

    @BeforeMethod            
    public void beforeMethod() throws Exception {            
        // set up appium        
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();        
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Browser");        
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");        
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Android Emulator");        
        capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "4.4.2");        
        WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(        
                http://****:4723/wd/hub), capabilities);
        driver.get("http://www.yahoo.com");        
    }            

    @Test            
    public void f() {            

    }            

    @AfterMethod            
    public void afterMethod() {            
        driver.quit();        
    }            

}
```

Comment: Getting the same error? You got any solution?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the below URL to `http://0.0.0.0:9515/wd/hub` instead of `****:4723`...

> `WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(http://****:4723/wd/hub), capabilities);`

Chromedriver's port defaults to 9515, not 4723. **[You should read the documentation on this. There are other capabilities that need to be set correctly](http://appium.io/slate/en/master/?ruby#toc_51)** (like `BROWSER_NAME`)

Answer (score 0):

The safest way to set for android capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.android()

PS: You got session is not created because your script is not able to connect to selenium node/hub; you should check your configuration

As in your post stacktrace, it connects to http://**:9515/ (not like in your mentioned port 4723)

Answer (score 0):

Though this issue is quite an old one and a lot of definition has changed on appium client usage along with the chrome driver version updates as well. Yet to what I could figure out was that the issue here was this from the logs :

> ERROR: error: Chromedriver create session did not work. Status was 200
>   and body was
>   {"sessionId":"ba9a494082776d6b4836da850072cbcb","status":13,"value":{"message":"unknown
>   error: **Device emulator-5554 is already in use**\n  (Driver info:
>   chromedriver=2.9.248315,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86)"}}

which resulted further into :

> org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: A new session could
>   not be created. (Original error: **Did not get session redirect from
>   Chromedriver**) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace
>   information)

and hence *SessionNotCreatedException*.

***Simpler fix to this could be ensuring no other session is in progress before initiating another to avoid conflicts of ports and session failure.***

Answer (score 0):

Try running after commenting below statement

```
 capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "4.4.2");
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace old chrome driver to new chrome driver in appium location, it worked for me.

The Appium location should be something like:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-chromedriver\chromedriver\win\
```

Appium version : 1.4.16.1